# How to preview the ffmpeg command line while using ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Let's say I implement the following python script that uses [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python):

```
# facetime.py

import ffmpeg

ffmpeg \
    .input(
        'FaceTime',
        format='avfoundation',
        pix_fmt='uyvy422',
        framerate=30
    ) \
    .output(
        'out.mp4',
        pix_fmt='yuv420p',
        vframes=100
    ) \
    .run()
```

Is there a mechanism to print to the stdout the corresponding `ffmpeg` command that will be executed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it:

```
cmd = ffmpeg \
    .input(
        'FaceTime',
        format='avfoundation',
        pix_fmt='uyvy422',
        framerate=30
    ) \
    .output(
        'out.mp4',
        pix_fmt='yuv420p',
        vframes=100
    )

args = cmd.get_args()
print(f'Args: {args}')
```

Output:

```
Args: ['-f', 'avfoundation', '-framerate', '30', '-pix_fmt', 'uyvy422', '-i', 'FaceTime', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-vframes', '100', 'out.mp4']
```